# Not getting IDQ log while running using infacmd command

Tags: informatica, data-quality, informatica-powerexchange

We are running a shell script that runs a deployed IDQ mapping. I tried in unix directories to see if it created a mapping log file but no where i can see.

I checked in various directories under `"" <infa_home> "` folder but i could not trace the log file.

If you have come across the same situation, please do let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Which log you are looking for? Mapping/ workflow/ DIS/Webservice/Catalina?

All IDQ logs stored under `$HOME/infa_shared/log/disLogs/*`

Comment: not an answer. Supposed to be a comment.. if you dont have enough reputation, try to answer the questions which does not need any clarification from OP.

Comment: I answered the question related to the location of log files reside. How are you saying it's not an answer?